# Unable to parse Service-Now JSON Data

Tags: json, scala, api, servicenow

I am new to `Python`/`Scala`. Trying to read/parse a `JSON` file from `dataLake` using `Python` and `Scala` but unsuccessful. Is there something wrong with the `.JSON` schema. I have attached the `JSON` schema and the data frame screenshots. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "instance": {
            "link": "https://service-now.com/api/now/table/assessment_instance/3d2a2c44d720058ba859e03d2",
            "value": "3d2a2c44d720058ba859e03d2"
        },
        "string_value": "Very Good",
        "assign_to_order": "",
        "instance_question": {
            "link": "https://service-now.com/api/now/table/assessment_instance_question/022a2c44d720058ba859e03d7",
            "value": "022a2c44d720058ba859e03d7"
        },
        "template_definition": "",
         "metric_definition": {
            "link": "https://service-now.com/api/now/table/metric_definition/7758eb387233200dbba82cb0bfb",
            "value": "7758eb387233200dbba82cb0bfb"
        },
        "sys_updated_on": "207-07-0 02:3:3",
        "scaled_value": "4",
        "metric": {
            "link": "https://service-now.com/api/now/table/metric/542a2c44d720058ba859e03a4",
            "value": "542a2c44d720058ba859e03a4"
        },
        "sys_created_on": "203-2-04 2:34:08",
        "sys_domain": {
            "link": "https://service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global",
            "value": "global"
        },
        "weighted_value": "0.8",
        "source_id": {
            "link": "https://service-now.com/api/now/table/type/502a2c44d720",
            "value": "502a2c44d720058ba859e03a3"
        },
        "normalized_value": ".33",
        "source_table": "metric_type",
        "user": "",
        "sys_created_by": "admin"
    }
]
```

}

```
 val asmt_metric_result = spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
 .json(s"c:/servicenow/asmt_metric_result/2021/09/28/08/32/asmt_metric_result_000000.json")
 asmt_metric_result.show(false)
```

[image: JSON SCHEMA]
[image: Scala Null Values]

[image: PrintSchema]

[image: asmt_metric_result_show]

Comment: Unfortunately it is difficult to help you with the few infos and not readable pictures. Please post your code, explain what you tried and what is not wrorking for you right now

Comment: Check json validity here: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Hi @CarloPrato Both codes (Json schema and Scala) in the questions

Comment: Hi @Kaushal28, i already checked the json validity and it is a valid file but still not seeing the data using the above scala code.

Comment: What happens if you add `asmt_metric_result .printSchema() ` ?

Comment: Hi @CarloPrato Schema image added to my post. Thanks

Comment: and with `asmt_metric_result.show(2, false, true)` ?

Comment: Hi @CarloPrato screenshot added to post. Thanks

Comment: my bad i was supposed to write `asmt_metric_result.show(2, 25, true)` . btw i'm just trying to see if we can output any meaningful data. it looks like the JSON has been successfully parsed. have you tried querying the dataframe, or yo just need to make the show to work?

Comment: As far as I have tried, the standard way of parsing json in scala is to define case classes corresponding to the hierarchy of your json objects, and then to use a library such as `spray` or `circe` for parsing it into an object of them. you can find examples on stack overflow, too.

Comment: Hi @CarloPrato i have updated the post with screenshot, seeing Null